# Want to deploy to servers in parallel using Groovy

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, groovy, deployment, parallel-processing

I am trying to Deploy to a list of servers in parallel to save some time. The names of servers are listed in a collection: *serverNames*

The original code was:

```
serverNames.each({
def server = new Server([steps: steps, hostname: it, domain: "test"])
        server.stopTomcat()
        server.ssh("rm -rf ${WEB_APPS_DIR}/pc*")
        PLMScriptUtils.secureCopy(steps, warFileLocation, it, WEB_APPS_DIR)
      })
```

Basically i want to stop the tomcat, rename a file and then copy a war file to a location using the following lines:

```
    server.stopTomcat()
    server.ssh("rm -rf ${WEB_APPS_DIR}/pc*")
    PLMScriptUtils.secureCopy(steps, warFileLocation, it, WEB_APPS_DIR)
```

The original code was working properly and it took 1 server from the collection serverNames and performed the 3 line to do the deploy.
But now i have requirement to run the deployment to the servers listed in *serverNames* parallely

Below is my new modified code:

```
def threads = []      
def th
      
serverNames.each({
    def server = new Server([steps: steps, hostname: it, domain: "test"])
    th = new Thread({
        steps.echo "doing deployment"
        server.stopTomcat()
        server.ssh("rm -rf ${WEB_APPS_DIR}/pc*")
        PLMScriptUtils.secureCopy(steps, warFileLocation, it, WEB_APPS_DIR) 
    })
    threads << th
  })
threads.each {
    steps.echo "joining thread"
    it.join()
    }
threads.each {
    steps.echo "starting thread"
    it.start()
    }
```

The echo statements were added to visualize the flow.

With this the output is coming as:

```
joining thread
joining thread
joining thread
joining thread
starting thread
starting thread
starting thread
starting thread
```

The number of servers in the collection was 4 hence 4 times the thread is being added and started. but it is not executing the 3 lines i want to run in parallel, which means "doing deployment" is not being printed at all and later the build is failing with an exception.

Note that i am running this Groovy code as a pipeline through Jenkins this whole piece of code is actually a function called **deploy** of the class **deployment** and my pipeline in jenkins is creating an object of the class deployment and then calling the deploy function

Can anyone help me with this ? I am stuck like hell with this one. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [parallel step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel). In scripted pipelines (which you seem to be using), you can pass it a map of thread name to action (as a Groovy closure) which is then run in parallel.

```
deployActions = [
    Server1: {
         // stop tomcat etc.
    },
    Server2: {
         ...
    }
]

parallel deployActions
```

It is much simpler and the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: So can this be done: ????


`serverNames.each({
    deployActions += [
    def server = new Server([steps: steps, hostname: it, domain: "test"])
        steps.echo "doing deployment"
        server.stopTomcat()
        server.ssh("rm -rf ${WEB_APPS_DIR}/pc*")
        PLMScriptUtils.secureCopy(steps, warFileLocation, it, WEB_APPS_DIR)
    ]
})

parallel deployActions`

Comment: sorry not able to put the comments properly somehow :-(

Comment: I think deployActions need to be a map, not a list and it needs to contain closures in curly brackets (anything that acts like a function). So something like deployActions += ["server 1": {...}]